# Why eloquent model relationships do not use parenthesis and how do they work?

Tags: php, function, object, methods, eloquent

I kept searching the web for an hour but couldn't figure this out. If we look at the eloquent relationships documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

The example User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

Just below it, how to access the phone number of a user with id=1:

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```

Why is it `phone` and not `phone()` and what is the difference?

Also how does it work? If I try to call an `object->name` without parenthesis in my code PHP thinks I am looking for a class variable named `name`?

Some extra information:

It looks like phone is returning object(App\Models\Phone) and phone() is returning object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne)

If I run the code below:

```
User::find(1)->phone->count()
```

Framework executes following SQL statements:

```
select * from `phone` where `phone`.`user_id` = '1' and `phone`.`user_id` is not null limit 1
select count(*) as aggregate from `phone`
```

If I run the code below:

```
User::find(1)->phone()->count()
```

Framework executes following SQL statement:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `phone` where `phone`.`user_id` = '1' and `phone`.`user_id` is not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Laravel/Eloquent and you would need to show the `find()` method for more information, but `User::find(1)` returns an object so the `->phone` accesses the `phone` property of that object.  This has nothing to do with the `find()` method that you have shown.  It is shorter than this that would do the same:

```
$obj = User::find(1);
$phone = $obj->phone;
```

Do a `var_dump($obj);` and you should see a `phone` property.  If not, then another possibility is that the class implements a `__get()` magic method so that when you attempt to access the `phone` property it runs the `phone()` method and returns the value.

As for the first explanation, the same can be done with arrays:

```
function test() { return array('phone'=>'713-555-1212'); }

echo test()['phone'];
```

Comment: What I wanted to know was why $obj->phone instead of $obj->phone() because the user object has a phone() function?

Comment: They are completely different things.  `User::find(1)->phone;` does not call the `phone()` function.  It is an object variable/property of the object that is returned by `find()`. Another possibility is `__get()`.  Edited.

Comment: It looks like phone is returning object(App\Phone) and phone() is returning object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne). Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I checked the Eloquent\Model and there is some custom __get() function. I will still wait a little bit to see if there comes more detailed answer or not before marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 25):

One way of thinking about it is that the `public function phone()` function defines the relationship, so using `$obj->phone()` would get you the Eloquent relationship itself (not the results of that relationship) which you could then modify with various query builder elements if you wanted.

Leaving out the brackets is the Eloquent shorthand for adding `->get()` or `->first()` at the end of the expression (Eloquent knows which to use based on if it's a hasOne, hasMany, etc. relationship, as defined in the function), which returns an Eloquent collection.

So, `$obj->phone` is the same as `$obj->phone()->first()`.

Comment: Thanks! have found that using `$obj->phone` is more reliable than using `$obj->phone()->first()`... the latter sometimes loses track of what $obj is and just returns me the first phone number in the table rather than the phone number of $obj.

Comment: If that’s happening, there is likely something else going on. While `$obj->phone` may be simpler, it should have no effect on “reliability”.