# Laravel : insert into pivot table

Tags: laravel, tinker

I'm trying to connect profiles with groups using a pivot table. What I want is to use tinker to add students profiles in study groups.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't make tinker write to the DB (I know how to do it with OneToOne and oneToMany relationships).

My Profile model has the following function :

```
    public function isStudentInGroup() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

My Group model has the following function :

```
    public function hasStudents() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class);
}
```

In tinker, I start by grabbing a Profile and a group :

```
$profile = Profile::find(1);
$group = Group::find(1);
```

Then I want to add the group to the isStudentInGroup collection. How do I do it? Here's what I've tried until now. No matter what I do, everytime I use fresh() I see an empty collection.

```
$profile->isStudentInGroup->save($group);
$profile->isStudentInGroup->save($group->id);
$profile->isStudentInGroup->attach($group->id);
Profile::find(1)->isStudentInGroup->push(1)->update();
Profile::find(1)->isStudentInGroup->push(1)->save();
```

These all give BadMethodCallException errors.

A promising syntax was this one :

```
$profile->isStudentInGroup->push($group)
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4646
 all: [
   App\Models\Group {#5012
     id: "1",
     start_time: "2022-09-05 18:10:00",
     end_time: "2022-09-05 19:00:00",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#5020
       profile_id: "1",
       group_id: "1",
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

But then, if I tried to $profile->save(); or $profile->update(); I would get the following

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.'
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

Thanks to matiaslauriti I got the syntax right:

```
$profile->isStudentInGroup()->save($group);
```

I also went fishing for knowledge and found this related question with a helpful answer from McHobbes that helped me understand the logic behind the parentheses.
[Why eloquent model relationships do not use parenthesis and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308513/why-eloquent-model-relationships-do-not-use-parenthesis-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon me if I did not understand, but you want to make a relation between those relationships, so you have to run:

```php
$profile->isStudentInGroup()->save($group->id);
```

That should trigger storing that group inside that relationship. If it does not work, I think this will should (or may also work):

```php
$profile->isStudentInGroup()->attach($group->id);
```

But you must use the relationship, not the `Collection`. You are mixing relationships objects with Collections, that is why the error says:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.

A Collection does not have `update` or `save` as it is a collection, it can't be saved anywhere, but a relationship can.

Comment: That was almost it. I still had to deal with a "TypeError: Argument 1 must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, int given". This made the trick: >>> $profile->isStudentInGroup()->save($group);

I must admit that I don't fully understand the implications of what you said, but you've proven more helpful than 2 hours of headscratching and googling. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ValentinMassart glad I was of help! So, remember that when you create a relation (you create a method returning `HasOne`, `HasMany`, `BelongsTo`, or `BelongsToMany`), and when you want to interact with the relation's query, you use `relationName()` (as a method), but when you want to directly get data and use the model or collection (depending on the relationship), you use `relationName` (as a property). Because you want to attach (relate) a model to another one, you must use the relationship method because you tell this using a query, not a collection

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, it makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
App\Models\Profile::find(1)->isStudentInGroup;
```

i hope it was useful .

Comment: Accessing the profile model is not the problem. I have used tinker to write to my DB using 1-to-1 and 1-to-many relationships before, so I'm almost 100% certain that there's something specific to the many-to-many relationships that I'm missing.